# Quilljs how to prevent reset line height when click other button

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, quill

I am creating text editor using Quilljs 1.3.7, I use Nuxt2 and Vue 2.
I create custom Line Height feature, together with built-in Bold and Italic of this library.
The Line height feature work fine. But when click button Italic or Bold, the line height is totally reset.

Can anyone please advise a solution to prevent this reset. I want to keep line height state when click Bold/Italic.

Link to my code is here:
[CodeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/wandering-flower-2ylm9y?file=%2Fpages%2Findex.vue%3A122%2C3)

Thank you.